# How to avoid database ID collisions in a distributed system

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am writing a java application for a computer science class. My question is less of a problem in the scope of this project but could cause havoc in the real world and my class mates and I cannot think of a solution. This is a system that is design to run on clients then contact a database to read and write information.

Scenario: 
The order object is comprised of an order Id, some other attributes and an array of items. Each item has an id so the best way we could figure to store them would be to use a table where each row has the order id and a corresponding item id. Simple enough so far. The issue is that in order to have unique ids we must have the database set them. This is easily done with auto-increment, now the order id is created during insertion of the order into the database. the next step is retrieving that new order id from the database and using it to add our items to the second table. The main issue here is that between those 2 steps someone could create a new order and this would cause the second order created to have all the items assigned to it rather than the first order.

We understand a client server model would fix this by having a single client interact with the database rather than multiple but is there truly no fix for this issue other than moving to a client/server model?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to fix this, just one of which is to place your insert statement into a stored function in the database that you call rather than doing the insert directly.  That way when you call the function it does the insert and returns the ID back rather than having to go and retrieve it, meaning you will always have the correct ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-incremented numbers are ideally not right choice as it gives an opportunity to query and extract information based on serially assigned ID. This is where UUID usually come into picture. Most of the databases offer generation of UUID along with different strategies. In your case, since you have tagged your question with MySQL, you can have a look at the following documentation

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

The value generated using UUID is assumed to be unique (even across machines, the generation logic considers MAC address). As documentation suggests, there are still chances that it might fail but that is a very rare scenario.

Another option is to generate your own UUID which considers a member/node ID while generating random portion. That will ensure you will have unique values across hosts.